# Python: Randomly remove duplicates among multiple lists

Tags: python

Given

```
x = [0,1,2,3]
y = [0,4,3,5]
z = [1,6,7,8]
```

I need something that removes all duplicates over all three lists randomly.
So the desired outcome would be something like:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [0,4,5]
z = [6,7,8]
```

Running it another time should give a different distribution like for example:

```
x = [0,1,2,3]
y = [4,5]
z = [6,7,8]
```

All questions I've already found (like this one for example [Remove both duplicates in multiple lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839690/remove-both-duplicates-in-multiple-lists-python)) remove duplicates per list.

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT:
Here is my current fruitless effort:

```
duplicatelist = []
    for number in y:
        if number in x:
            duplicatelist.append(number)
    for number in z:
        if number in x or number in y:
            duplicatelist.append(number)

#now I don*t know how to continue
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've run my head against the issue multiple times. I was thinking looping through all of them and then adding the duplicates to a fourth list or dictionary but I didn't know a good way to use that fourth list to remove the duplicates from the first three.

Comment: Show us some code!

Comment: Added but as I said, I haven't gotten far.

Comment: What does "_which also geek_" mean?

Comment: Nothing, that was a brainlag I've now removed.

Comment: What are the criteria of removing duplicates?  Should one of them always be removed?  What if there's 4 or more equal items?

Comment: After the operation there should be no duplicates left. The rest should be completely random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start randomly (means x,y, z which one to treat first) you could get what you want.

```
import random
def rm_dup(**kwargs):
    inp = kwargs
    duplicate = set()
    keys = list(inp.keys())
    random.shuffle(keys)
    out = {k: [] for k in inp.keys()}

    for key in keys:
        for v in inp[key]:
            if v not in duplicate:
                out[key].append(v)
                duplicate.add(v)
    return out
```

example outs:

```
out = rm_dup(x=x,y=y,z=z)
print(out)
```

{'x': [2], 'y': [0, 4, 3, 5], 'z': [1, 6, 7, 8]}

{'x': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5], 'z': [6, 7, 8]}
...

Comment: Hi amirhm! I'll only get to try it this evening but thanks a lot already for your suggestion. I'll let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Hi Amirhm! Thanks so much! It works beautifully!

Comment: @Difio You are very welcome. I believe you can mark it as answer accepted.